# Syncing Android and IOS app with backend after live in future updates

Tags: android, ios, node.js, react-native, backend

So the app I am building for a client is in final stage of release. I would like to get some help from here about syncing the API with future updates on app. I will give a scenario:

Lets say our app is live with version 1.0.0 on both  IOS and Android. Server keeps track of version number and if it does not match(will always be less if not updated) it tells to force update the app. Everything works. The problem arises here.

Lets say we need to provide some feature update on 1.0.1 we make the code ready on backend but does not make it live on production until the apps are live with new update otherwise old app might not work properly with new API changes. If any one of the app(lets say IOS) is live with v1.0.1 we need to make the backend live. It will work on IOS. But for Android if v1.0.1 is not live yet the old app will say to force update since version is already changed in backend. but since its still not yet live user are now stuck with force update screen.

The solution I came up with is to fire 2 express server with same code but 2 branches for production like production-ios and production-android.

How do you guys handle these kind of thing? Its my first big FullStack app and need to figure this out soon.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you handling the app update version tracking?
Is it done via JSON or some other text file content?

JSON would be a better option to set multiple parameters like:

```json
{
  "app_update_details": {
    "app_version": "1.0.1",
    "ios": true,
    "android": false
  }
}
```

Parse this Json accordingly on your platform (Android, iOS).
This way you could the `android` flag to handle Android use cases & same for iOS.